# Encryption using System.Security.Cryptography is very slow

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, encryption

I noticed some slowness on my real-life application and I noticed it is due to the encryption taking way too much time.

To demonstrate the issue I create a plain form with just a button encrypting the information coming from the Orders table found in the Northwind Database. The code shown below on my local machine takes about 20 seconds for 830 records, removing the encryption takes < 1 second. Of course in my real-life situation, I am not encrypting 830 times but still, the difference is noticeable and I need to encrypt the information.

I tried to add the function directly in my form, instead of calling it but it didn't change anything as far as speed is concerned.

Any idea?

```
    Dim cTools As New cTools

    Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conNorth").ToString)
    objConn.Open()

    Dim s As String = ""
    Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT  OrderID FROM Orders ORDER BY OrderID"
    Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand(sSQL, objConn)
    objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    Dim objRdr As SqlDataReader
    objRdr = objCmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim dtStart As Date = System.DateTime.Now

    Response.Write("<br>Before With Encrypt " & System.DateTime.Now & "<br>")

    Do While objRdr.Read()
        s = cTools.Encrypt(objRdr("OrderID"))
    Loop

    Dim dtEnd As Date = System.DateTime.Now

    Response.Write("After With Encrypt " & System.DateTime.Now & "<br>")
    Response.Write("Duration With Encrypt " & DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, dtStart, dtEnd) & "<br>")

    objRdr.Close()

    objConn.Close()
    objConn.Dispose()
```

The process is calling the function shown below:

```
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Security.Cryptography

    Public Class cTools
        Public Function Encrypt(clearText As String) As String
            Dim EncryptionKey As String = "MAKV2SPBNI99212"
            Dim clearBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText)
            Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
                Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D,
             &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65,
             &H76})
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
                Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                    Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length)
                        cs.Close()
                    End Using
                    clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
                End Using
            End Using
            Return clearText
        End Function
        Public Function Decrypt(cipherText As String) As String
            Dim EncryptionKey As String = "MAKV2SPBNI99212"
            cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+")
            Dim cipherBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText)
            Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
                Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D,
                 &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65,
                 &H76})
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
                Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                    Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                        cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length)
                        cs.Close()
                    End Using
                    cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray())
                End Using
            End Using
            Return cipherText
        End Function
    End Class
```

Comment: In `Encrypt()` and `Decrypt()`, key and IV are derived using PBKDF2 (s. [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-7.0)). PBKDF2 is intentionally slow to slow down attackers. The loop containing `Encrypt()` or `Decrypt()` reduces the performance strongly. Since password and salt are static, you could do the key/IV derivation before the loop and pass the derived key and IV to `Encrypt()` and `Decrypt()`.

Comment: Note that hard-encoded values for password and salt are generally vulnerabilities (furthermore, a random salt should be used, which is generated during encryption and must be stored somewhere for decryption)..

Comment: @Topaco I do not understand what you mean by " you could do the key/IV derivation".

Comment: Move the `Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(...)` part before the loop, and pass `pdb.GetBytes(32)` as key and `pdb.GetBytes(16)` as IV to `Encrypt()` and `Decrypt()`, so that the key derivation is done once and not for each `Read()` call.

Comment: It indeed improved the speed but marginally. From 23 seconds down to 18 seconds. I found another method I had used before, using Rijndael, and it is fast.